# The block X was assigned to the invalid region footer and has been disabled

Tags: theming, blocks

I am seeing the following:

The block X was assigned to the invalid region footer and has been disabled.
The block Y was assigned to the invalid region footer and has been disabled.
The block Z was assigned to the invalid region footer and has been disabled.
The block W was assigned to the invalid region search and has been disabled.

Here is my code

```
array(
  'module' => 'W',
  'delta' => 'form',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => 1,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'search',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache' => -1,
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
),
array(
  'module' => 'X',
  'delta' => '1',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => true,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'footer',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache'  => -1,
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
),
array(
  'module' => 'Y',
  'delta' => '2',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => true,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'footer',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache'  => -1,
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
),
array(
  'module' => 'Z',
  'delta' => '3',
  'theme' => $admin_theme,
  'status' => true,
  'weight' => 0,
  'region' => 'footer',
  'pages' => '',
  'cache'  => -1,
  'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
),
```

);

Any suggestion greatly appreciate it. I have other blocks that have properly worked using this method with the custom theme. But the above in $admin_theme = 'seven'; are not working.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because regions are *theme specific*. The only way you can have cross theme block export/import is to have the same regions (machine name) defined in your admin theme.